# How to get shell with busybox on android?

Tags: busybox

I installed busybox free on my android device. I have super user and stuff. When I click on the busybox widget, it gets me to the configuration utility where I can install / uninstall. It is installed. How can I execute the busybox binary now?

Comment: Use one of the many Terminal Emulator apps out on the Play Store and run either one the commands or `busybox` itself. Hint: search the Play Store for *Terminal*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**BusyBox**: [**The Swiss Army Knife of Embedded Linux**](http://www.busybox.net/about.html)

> BusyBox combines tiny versions of ***many common UNIX utilities into a
>   single small executable***. It provides replacements for most of the
>   utilities you usually find in GNU fileutils, shellutils, etc. The
>   utilities in BusyBox generally have fewer options than their
>   full-featured GNU cousins; however, the options that are included
>   provide the expected functionality and behave very much like their GNU
>   counterparts. BusyBox provides a fairly complete environment for any
>   small or embedded system.
>
> BusyBox has been written with size-optimization and limited resources
>   in mind. ***It is also extremely modular so you can easily include or
>   exclude commands*** (or features) at compile time. This makes it easy
>   to customize your embedded systems. To create a working system, **just
>   add some device nodes in `/dev`**, a few configuration files in
>   **`/etc`**, and a Linux kernel.

also, as ***GiantTree*** said,

you need to download the ([**Terminal Emulator - Google play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)).

and after install (*and also install the binary and get root permission*), you can use the terminal serve as more Permissions and it support Busy Box Binaries.
This is the Syntax of use this project :

```
/bin/busybox ls
```

More information :

[**Command Help - BusyBox**](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)

Comment: OH. Makes a lot of sense. I'm used to having busybox self contained however... Thanks